# Pressing a button populate a google map with markers from an external json file

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, google-maps-markers

I have the above code and I want to have an external json file not an embedded as it is shown. Pressing a button(on the map at the top left side), all the markers have to be placed on the map.(These markers from the json file via ajax call).And pressing a second button the markers have to disappear. And all these without the use of jquery. Have you got any suggestions?

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My map</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var markers = [
    {
        "title": 'Aksa Beach',
        "lat": '19.1759668',
        "lng": '72.79504659999998',
        "description": 'Aksa Beach is a popular beach and a vacation spot in Aksa village at Malad, Mumbai.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Juhu Beach',
        "lat": '19.0883595',
        "lng": '72.82652380000002',
        "description": 'Juhu Beach is one of favourite tourist attractions situated in Mumbai.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Girgaum Beach',
        "lat": '18.9542149',
        "lng": '72.81203529999993',
        "description": 'Girgaum Beach commonly known as just Chaupati is one of the most famous public beaches in Mumbai.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Jijamata Udyan',
        "lat": '18.979006',
        "lng": '72.83388300000001',
        "description": 'Jijamata Udyan is situated near Byculla station is famous as Mumbai (Bombay) Zoo.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Sanjay Gandhi National Park',
        "lat": '19.2147067',
        "lng": '72.91062020000004',
        "description": 'Sanjay Gandhi National Park is a large protected area in the northern part of Mumbai city.'
    }
    ];
        window.onload = function () {
            LoadMap();
        }
    function LoadMap() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
            });
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent("<div style = 'width:200px;min-height:40px'>" + data.description + "</div>");
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
            latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
        }
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
        map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
    }
</script>
<div id="dvMap" style="width: 600px; height: 600px">
</div>
```